# c# combobox autocomplete suggestappend issues

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

In my WinForm-Application i have some ComboBoxes with `AutoCompleteMode` as `SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource.ListItems`.

If the combobox is empty and i type 'f', the list pops up with the entry 'foo' in it. The text is auto appended to foo. If i jump to the next control by hitting tab, the combobox selects the entry foo. Fine.

If the combobox has already selected entry 'foo' and i type 'f', the list pops up with the entry 'foo' in it, but the text is not auto appended to foo. If i jump to next control by hitting tab, the combobox doesn't select the entry foo, the text being displayed stayed 'f'. I want it to have the same behavior like above.

Answer (score 1):

What about using combobox's `Leave` event like this,

```
private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string item = source.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text));  
     //search string inside source of suggests and if there is a match get the first one
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) 
     {
          int index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(item); // find it inside combobox items
          comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index; // and select it

      }
}
```

Hope helps,